# Fastfify auth module, what is the difference between { relation: 'and' } and { run: 'all' }?

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, permissions, fastify

I'm reading the docs here and not sure I understand the difference between the all/and options: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-auth

It seems like if you use `{ relation: 'and' }` you would get the same result at `{ run: 'all' }`.

Are they saying that `{ run: 'all' }` will not change the and/or logic, but it will run all the auth functions regardless? If that's what it does, I'm not sure I understand the use case there. You want to keep running more code even after you've determined you're going to continue the request anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like if you use { relation: 'and' } you would get the same result at { run: 'all' }.

No, because `relation: and` will stop the execution whenever one auth function is **unsuccessful**, meanwhile `run: all` will execute all the auth functions whatever the result is.

> You want to keep running more code even after you've determined you're going to continue the request anyway?

A real use case was:

- you support multiple custom auth types (read from the header, read from cookies or read from the body)
- each auth function adds to the `request` object some data after a heavy operation (decrypt)

Now, if you have some endpoints that support to be called by an auth user or a server-to-server token plus you are reading from the db additional user's roles, if you don't run all the auth function:

- the auth user will get an `server token not valid`
- the server will get a `user token not valid`
- setting the `relation: or` would skip the auth function that reads the user's data from a database

So, in order to:

- keep one single `route` definition
- do not duplicate the `readFromDb` across all the endpoints
- decrypt the token once

the `run: all` option is necessary.

counter side:

- you need to run the `if (!req.auth)` check, in your handler

> You want to keep running more code even after you've determined you're going to continue the request anyway?

Yes, you are right, but as said in the application context a function that does a boolean check if the job must be done (eg: `if(req.headers.token)` is nothing compared to the necessity to get the token data once and don't duplicate the code that read the user from the db (as it was complex due the legacy rules).

```
    fastify.route({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/',
      preHandler: fastify.auth([
        function authUserToken (request, reply, done) {
          if (validUserAuth(request.headers.authorization)) {
            request.auth = { from: 'header' }
            done()
          } else {
            done(new Error('you shall not pass'))
          }
        },
        function authServerToken (request, reply, done) {
          if (validServerAuth(request.headers['x-auth-s2s'])) {
            request.auth = { from: 'server' }
            done()
          } else {
            done(new Error('you shall not pass'))
          }
        },
        function authAugmentation (request, reply, done) {
          if (request.auth?.from === 'header') {
            request.auth = { from: 'server', user: readFromDb() }
          }
          done()
        }
      ], { run: 'all' }),
      handler: (req, reply) => {
        if (!req.auth) {
          return reply.send(new Error('auth failed'))
        }
        return reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
      }
    })
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `relation: and` will stop the execution whenever one auth function is *un*successful?

Comment: I think I am not understanding what `relation: 'and'` does if it stops running strategies after the first *successful* auth function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The `and` stops to execute to the first unsuccessful auth function. I fixed the answer. The `or` stops at the first successful auth function. Sorry the misprint